# fetch gmail with oauth2

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, gmail-imap

I am working on oauth authentication for my app and am planning to use Oauth2.
Can someone tell if Gmail supports fetching Inbox by the Oauth2 access-token.I saw it is possible to do this by the Oauth1 token but I found that Oauth1 support is deprecated by Google now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, just OAuth 1.0 right now.

Comment: OAuth 2 support is available now: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working, Ruby example of fetching email from Google using their XOAUTH2 protocol:

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, usessl = true, certs = nil, verify = false)
imap.authenticate('XOAUTH2', 'example@gmail.com', 'oauth2_access_token_goes_here')
imap.select('INBOX')
imap.search(['ALL']).each do |message_id|

    msg = imap.fetch(message_id,'RFC822')[0].attr['RFC822']
    mail = Mail.read_from_string msg

    puts mail.subject
    puts mail.text_part.body.to_s
    puts mail.html_part.body.to_s

end
```

Note: This example uses the [ruby `mail`](https://github.com/mikel/mail) gem and the [`gmail_xoauth`](https://github.com/nfo/gmail_xoauth) gem, so you will need that installed for this code sample to work.

Also, retrieving the OAuth2 access token is not shown in this example. [Here's an example using the ruby OmniAuth gem.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12850157/48523)